# Using CKEditor on Django Blog, How can I get django to render the html from ckeditor?

Tags: django, ckeditor

I had done this with markdown before following the book practical django projects but now I wish to use CKEditor on my blog and it just spits out the raw HTML  I've checked docs. I imagine I am just not using the correct filter? IF anybody knows the answer please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to display HTML on your template you need to use the `safe` filter ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#safe)).

Example:

```
{{ my_html_text|safe }}
```

Comment: I want the html to be rendered, I do not want the raw html. I am using CKEditor to make blog posts and it is giving me raw html. I will look at documentatiom -- I already have been but have not found solid answer. Thanks -- Thank you, I had tried this but I was doing it on the wrong template lols :) ty again